# Unable to add attribute on dom ready using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.4

I have the [code here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mZVc/).

We are using jquery 1.4.4 unable to update to newer version as of yet, where I can get my code to work.

So I need to on domready or on pageload, add attr to numerous `<a` tags. Can someone help me figure out a method where this is possible with javascript and/or the required version of jquery.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use event attributes if you have jQuery around?

Comment: @Bergi Thats a very good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***[.attr(index, callback)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)*** process to do it easily like below:

```
$('a').attr('href', function(index, oldAttr) {
    if (oldAttr.indexOf('test') >= 0) {
        $(this)
            .removeAttr('onclick')
            .get(0)
            .setAttribute("onclick", "test");
    }
});​
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3mZVc/7/)***

But if you want to use `.each()` then try like following:

```
$('a').each(function(index, element) {
    var el = $(element),
        hasHref = !el.attr('href'); // return true, if no href
    if( !hasHref ) {
        var href = el.attr('href'); 
        if( href.match('test').length || href.match('test-page').length ) {
         el
           .removeAttr("onclick")
           .get(0)
           .setAttribute("onclick", "test");
        }
    }
});​
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3mZVc/8/)***

Comment: It does the same as my original it removes but doesnt add it back.

Comment: thank you for your help, would also like users to check: http://jsfiddle.net/3mZVc/14/ as an alternative answer from @Bergi comment suggestion